# Искажения при повороте фигуры

Tags: canvas, javascript, графика

Собственно, есть canvas и на нём некая фигура (многоугольник). Мне нужно её повернуть на определённый угол, вычислив новые координаты точек. Простое преобразование.

Но присутствует следующая проблема: при одном повороте (на любой угол) фигура поворачивается вполне нормально, но если повернуть несколько раз, то она начинает искажаться (в итоге все точки съезжаются в одну). Например, анимация:
    setInterval("path.rotate(1)", 10);

Так и должно быть?.. И что делать?

Comment: А что за фреймворк, который позволяет крутить путь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо накапливается погрешность преобразований. В таких случаях обычно хранят оригинальную фигуру, и одноразово поворачивают на нужный угол например:

```
var angle = 0;
setInterval("path = original_path.clone();angle++; path.rotate(angle);",10);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я вообще так и делал, но хотелось узнать, почему так происходит).